# How to connect to Azure Devops git repo through databricks?

Tags: python, git, azure-devops, databricks-repos

I want to create a python notebook in databricks that will do the following -

1. Connect to Azure Devops Git repo
2. Make couple of changes in a yaml file
3. Commit the changes in the master branch
4. Push the changes back to repo

I tried the below code to achieve step 1:

```
import git

repo_url = <repo url>
pat_token = <token>
dbfs_path ='<dbfs_path>'

repo = git.Repo.clone_from(repo_url, dbfs_path, branch='master')
```

But I got the below error:

```
GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
  cmdline: git clone --branch=master -v <repo_url> <dbfs_path>
  stderr: 'Cloning into <dbfs_path>...
fatal: could not read Username for <repo_url>: No such device or address
```

I am not sure where to provide the username.